# Does the US operate 400-metre tall towers/antennas in Israel?

Tags: united-states, military, israel

Wikipedia had [this claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dimona_Radar_Facility&oldid=1176181750) up for about 15 years:

> Dimona Radar Facility (Hebrew: מתקן המכ"ם בדימונה) is a radar facility near Dimona, Israel, owned and operated by the United States.
>
> The Dimona Radar facility has two 400 meter (1,300 feet) tall radar towers designed to track ballistic missiles through space and provide ground-based missiles with the targeting data needed to intercept them.

And there's even [images](https://virtualglobetrotting.com/map/dimona-radar-facility-tallest-structures-in-israel/view/google/) in Google Maps to "prove" it:

[image]

OTOH I can't verify that the US operates those because all the other stories about "the Dimona Radar" or "Site 512" (which may or may not be exactly the same thing) talk about an AN/TPY2 which is hardly a tower:

[image]

E.g. stories that mention just the latter [Time (2012)](https://content.time.com/time/world/article/0,8599,2115955,00.html), [The Drive (2019)](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/14464/us-army-opens-permanent-base-in-southern-israel-as-trump-slams-iran-deal), [The American Security Project (2018)](https://www.americansecurityproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ref-0213-US-Military-Bases-and-Facilities-Middle-East.pdf).

So, does the US operate those fabled "400 meter" towers antennas in Israel *too*?

Comment: This may not be that notable of a claim one way or the other, given that the US has given Israel more than a hundred billion dollars in military aid. (Although Wikipedia should be corrected if it's indeed not accurate.)

Comment: Is the height of the towers supposed to be important to the claim? For example, would there be a political implication if they were taller or shorter?

Comment: I don't understand these questions about obviously top-secret military infrastructure because obviously you'll never know. To the extent any top secret US-Israeli join project has a 400m antenna, what would convincing proof of the operant even look like? Clearly, it's a joint project. Clearly it's top secret.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the American are operating a Radar that is located in Har Qeren, the 400 meter antennas are operated by Israel. From a [2008 article](https://www.makorrishon.co.il/nrg/online/1/ART1/795/368.html) talking about the detection devices that will be built. It's clear from the article that while the American radar and the 400m antennas were erected in the same time and are probably related to the same threat, they are distinct and one is operated by the IDF and the other by the US military. It does say that the Americans will share with Israel the information (or some of it) that will be obtained by their radar.

> בימים אלה מוקמים והולכים במהירות שני פרויקטים ענקיים בנגב, בעקבות המתיחות המתגברת בין ישראל ואיראן: האחת - אנטנות ענק, השנייה - תחנת מכ"ם אמריקנית.
>
> ...
>
> אנטנות הענק שיוקמו בנגב [...] לא ניתן לפרט לאיזו מטרה הן מיועדות. ניתן רק לומר שהן ישמשו את צה"ל
>
> ...
>
> ‫במקביל מתקדמות ההכנות להקמת תחנת המכ"ם האמריקנית בתדר אקס T־FBX באתר ליד הר קרן שבנגב המערבי.
>
> ...
>
> המכ"ם, מתוצרת רייתאון, יוצב בסמוך להר קרן ויופעל אך רק בידי חיילים אמריקנים.

> Because of the tension with Iran. At this time two huge projects are being build in the Negev: One - huge antennas, the second - an American radar station.
>
> ...
>
> The huge antennas that will be erected in the Negev [...] can't give detail for which purpose they are intended. Can only be said that they will be used by the IDF
>
> ...
>
> In parallel the preparation for the erection of an American Radar station in frequency X FBX-T in the Har Qeren site in the western Negev are on their way.
>
> ...
>
> The radar made by Raytheon will be deployed next to Har Qeren and will be operated exclusively by American soldiers.

The Har Qeren site is planned to be expanded: [The Intercept, Oct-27 2023: U.S. QUIETLY EXPANDS SECRET MILITARY BASE IN ISRAEL](https://theintercept.com/2023/10/27/secret-military-base-israel-gaza-site-512/)